# Query Specific Stored Proc / Schema with JTDS SqlServer Driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

I am writing some Java code to query a stored procedure in a SQLServer database.  My connection string looks like:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://address:port;database=dbname
```

Now when I try to call a stored procedure with the connection:

```
  String sql = "{call xyz.StoreProcNamedFoo(?,?,?,?)}";
```

I receive this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not find stored procedure 'xyz.StoreProcNamedFoo'.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2886)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2328)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:638)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:614)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:573)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.execute(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:764)
```

A DBA suggested he change the default schema to xyz, instead of abc.  That worked great, but he had to change it right back, since the default schema has to be abc.  My question is, how do I call this stored proc?

Comment: Funny, I tried Google searching for that and this post was the first link that came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed drivers from jtds to the official Microsoft release.  Works now.